# Determine last folder in URI / URL

Tags: php

I am new to php and trying to return true / false based upon the user url. (Using this in drupal)
So for example if the user is at:

http://www.example.com/training I want it to return true

http://www.example.com/training/home I want it to return true

http://www.example.com/browse/training/results/* I want it to return true

For anything else though I want it false.

http://www.example.com/training/backpacking I want it to return false.

My first ever php script has a bug...go figure. Anyway it doesn't show on anything that is not under training but it does show on training sub areas where it is not desired.

```
global $language;
$curr_uri = check_plain(request_uri());

if ($language->language == 'en')
    if (basename(dirname($curr_uri)) == 'training')
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
else
    return FALSE;
```

I understand the concept of what needs to be accomplished. I want to check for three specific uri's and not show on anything else. I also tried:

```
global $language;
$curr_uri = check_plain(request_uri());

if ($language->language == 'en')
    if ($curr_uri == '/training/home')
        return TRUE;
    else
        return FALSE;
else
    return FALSE;
```

Adnan...I'm not sure what your edit was but I found a typo and it is working now with this code:

```
<?php
  global $language;
  $curr_uri = check_plain(request_uri());

if ( $language->language == 'en')
  if($curr_uri == '/training/home' || $curr_uri == '/browse/training/results' )
    return TRUE;
  else
    return FALSE;
else
  return FALSE;
?>
```

Comment: even though you have only one statement after your `if` or `else` it's a good idea to use `{ }` for readability. On a related matter, I'm not sure I can see a pattern in the URLs, what do the "good" URLs have in common?

Comment: You can click the ["edited blah blah ago"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11832780/revisions) link and see the edits.

Comment: oh sure that makes sense. So I use {} like javascript. So new to php that I was taking the code snippets I was reading from Google literally and they didn't have the {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pairs = array(  array('training'),
                 array('training','home'),
                 array('browse','training','results'));

$urls = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

foreach($pairs as $pair){
  if ( !empty(array_diff($pair,$urls)) )
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a good idea to explain in a line or two the OP's mistake and what you did to correct it or just explain what your code is doing.

Comment: Ahhh another good way to solve the problem. Using the array would allow for more criteria without a run away if statement.